# what is "EOFError" in python and how to fix?

Tags: python

i got to solve a given task in codechef.
After submitting my code I get an error msg as "EOFError".
What does that mean and how to solve it? ----------

```
x=0 
arr = list() 
while (x!=42): 
    x= int(input("enter the number: ")) 
    arr.append(x) 
print(arr)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "./prog.py", line 5, in <module> 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

---

this is the error msg i get.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#EOFError

Comment: FWIW, I don't get an error with this code.

Comment: Could you add the link to the problem or the problem statement? Looks like the way you are processing the input does not match what the site is trying to run as a test on your submitted code. But impossible to judge without the problem statement

Comment: Works for me, but not using codechef.

Comment: I can get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` from your script IF I run it under python 2 and IF I just hit <RETURN> when prompted for a number.  This is because of the change in `input()`.  Make sure you are using python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure about the question, so i'm guessing the input format....

.

In this case i think you are inputting a list of integers till a 42 is encountered in the list... if that's the case, according to your code it will read x in different lines...

.

I think in this ques, list of elements is given in 1 line separated by spaces and not in separate lines...That's why it is showing end of file as the code is expecting more inputs in diff lines and there is only one line...

.

Now if input is like this

INPUT:

4 6 7 43 54 42

```
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
print(arr)
```

Output:

[4,6,7,43,54,42]

I think that's the case for your problem and enough to get started... If you find it helpful , upvote :)